# Question around using useContext and useReducer hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to practice using hooks and i am not able to wrap my head around it. 
I have a single component `MessageBoard` component that reads the data from state which just displays a simple list of messages.

I am passing down the `dispatch` and `state` via `createContext` so that the child components can consume it, which in-turn uses `useContext` in the child components to read the value.

When the page is refreshed, I expect to see the initial UI but it fails to render that the value in the context is undefined. I have already provided the initial state to the reducer when initializing it.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";

import MessageBoard from "./MessageBoard";

import MessagesContext from "../context/MessagesContext";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MessagesContext>
        <h2>Reaction</h2>
        <hr />
        <MessageBoard />
      </MessagesContext>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**MessageBoard.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import MessagesContext from "../context/MessagesContext";

function MessageBoard(props) {
  const { state } = useContext(MessagesContext);

  return (
    <div>
      {state.messages.map(message => {
        return (
          <div key={message.id}>
            <h4>{new Date(message.timestamp).toLocaleDateString()}</h4>
            <p>{message.text}</p>
            <hr />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MessageBoard;
```

**MessagesContext.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

import reducer, { initialState } from "../state/reducer";

export default function MessagesContext(props) {
  const Context = createContext(null);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        dispatch,
        state
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

Broken Example - https://codesandbox.io/s/black-dust-13kj2

Instead if I change the `MessagesContext` file a bit and instead the `Provider` is directly injected into the `App`, it works as expected. Wondering what I have misunderstood here and what might be going on ?

**MessagesContext.js**

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export default createContext(null);
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

import reducer, { initialState } from "../state/reducer";

import PublishMessage from "./PublishMessage";
import MessageBoard from "./MessageBoard";

import MessagesContext from "../context/MessagesContext";

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <div>
      <MessagesContext.Provider
        value={{
          dispatch,
          state
        }}
      >
        <h2>Reaction</h2>
        <hr />
        <PublishMessage />
        <hr />
        <MessageBoard />
      </MessagesContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Working Example - https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-meitner-vzhok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useContext` accepts a context object (the value returned from `React.createContext`) and returns the current context value for that context.

```
const MyContext = createContext(null);
const value = useContext(MyContext);
// MessagesContext Not a contex object.
const { state } = useContext(MessagesContext);
```

In the first example:

```
// export the context.
export const Context = createContext(null);

export default function MessagesContext(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        dispatch,
        state
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

and then use it:

```js
import { Context } from '../context/MessagesContext';

function MessageBoard() {
  const { state } = useContext(Context);
...
}
```

Working broken example:

[image: Edit Q-57103683-useContext]

Comment: D'oh, skimmed the code (didn't run the Sandboxes) and completely missed `useContext(MessageContext)` (`MessageContext` not actually being a Context!). Good spot.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Looks like this is what I misunderstood. I was using the Component and not the context object in this scenario. Also since the createContext was defined inside the component it was creating a new context object in render as well.